# Assign a variable in hyperlink using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I have defined a variable :

```
    <%int imageTypSelected = 0; %>
```

And I have these :

```
        <div class="imageToEdit" >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg", "Pr", new{Id = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false; ">A</a>             
        </div>

        <div class="imageToEdit" >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg_Alt1", "Pr", new{Id = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">B</a>           
        </div>

        <div class="imageToEdit" >
         <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg_Alt2", "Pr", new{Id = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
         <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false">C</a>            
        </div>
```

Now I want that when the user select the first hyperlink "1" assigns to the variable.
for second hyperlink "2" and for the last "3". But how? this variable will be post to a method in controller later. How can I have this assignment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the value from the controller back into your view; either make it a part of your model, or add it to the `ViewBag`. You can then assign it like this:

```
<% int imageTypSelected = Model.ImageTypeSelected; %>
```

...or like this:

```
<% int imageTypSelected = (int)ViewBag.ImageTypeSelected; %>
```

Comment: Actually I want the reverse of that. I need to pass a value to controller and then the controller must decide what to do according to the passed value

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Your links each open a JQuery dialog; what's on that dialog?

Comment: I don't know why I cant post my code! It will be disappear after adding!

Comment: Oh dear! I'm assuming your dialogs contain a form or link which sends data to your controller; you'll need to include the `imageTypSelected` variable value in that form or link and add an `int imageTypSelected` parameter to your action. You can then assign the action parameter value to the model or `ViewBag`.